# Categorizing Consecutive Months With Zero Values Into Buckets

Tags: excel, powerbi, dax, powerquery

I've constructed a data model around utilization for my company's fleet within PowerQuery. We have a number of different columns in the data model. Specifically, mileage, VIN, start date, and end date (see below for example table).

```
Mileage | VIN | Start Date | End Date |
0       | 123 | 6/1/18     | 6/30/18  |
0       | 123 | 7/1/18     | 7/31/18  |
0       | 123 | 8/1/18     | 8/31/18  |
0       | 123 | 9/1/18     | 9/30/18  |
0       | 123 | 10/1/18    | 10/31/18 |
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is if mileage is equal to 0 for one month it is categorized into a bucket labeled 0-30 days, if mileage is equal to 0 for two consecutive months it is categorized as 31-60 days, and 0 mileage for more than 3 consecutive months would be categorized as >60 days. From the example above, this vehicle would be categorized in the ">60 days" bucket. Is there an easy way to do this within the data model using DAX? Please let me know if you have any follow up questions. Thank you!

Comment: I suggest creating a couple calculated helper columns that sum the milage in the trailing 2 and 3 months and categorizing based on if those columns have zeros in them.

Comment: Could you tell a bit more about the endresult you are looking for? Do you need a new table? A calculated column? A measure? What would it look like?

Comment: @MarcoVos I’m anticipating a calculated column doing the job. Additionally, the end result would place each VIN that hits the month criteria within a corresponding category. For example, from 6/1-6/30 VIN 123 would be in the 0-30 days bucket, from 7/1-7/31 it would be in the 31-60 days bucket, from 8/1 and on it would fall into the >60 days bucket (until it would receive a mileage reading greater than 0). This logic would hold true for any VIN that meets the same criteria. Let me know if this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as a Calculated Column:

```
Buckets =
VAR rowDate = 'myTable'[ Start Date ]
VAR previousDate =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'myTable'[ Start Date ] ),
        FILTER (
            ALLEXCEPT ( myTable, myTable[ VIN ] ),
            'myTable'[ Start Date ] < rowDate
        )
    )
VAR prePreviousDate =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'myTable'[ Start Date ] ),
        FILTER (
            ALLEXCEPT ( myTable, myTable[ VIN ] ),
            'myTable'[ Start Date ] < previousDate
        )
    )
VAR PreviousMileage =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'myTable'[Mileage ] ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( 'myTable', 'myTable'[ VIN ] ),
        'myTable'[ Start Date ] = previousDate
    )
VAR PrePreviousMileage =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( 'myTable'[Mileage ] ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( 'myTable', 'myTable'[ VIN ] ),
        'myTable'[ Start Date ] = prePreviousDate
    )
RETURN
    SWITCH (
        TRUE (),
        'myTable'[Mileage ] + IF ( ISBLANK ( PreviousMileage ), 1, PreviousMileage )
            + IF ( ISBLANK ( PrePreviousMileage ), 1, PrePreviousMileage )
            = 0, "> 60 Days",
        'myTable'[Mileage ] + IF ( ISBLANK ( PreviousMileage ), 1, PreviousMileage )
            = 0, "31 to 60 Days",
        'myTable'[Mileage ] = 0, "0 to 30 Days",
        "No Days"
    )
```

The result looks like this. I added some values for testing.

[image]

Comment: This works great! However, let's say we add another layer of complexity to the problem. What if there is another column that accounts for telematics units that are not reporting. If it's not reporting, the row will have the entry "NRU" in it. With this in mind, I'd like to exclude those rows with non-reporting units from the logic. For example, let's say for VIN 123 from 7/1-7/31 the telematics device was not reporting and was labeled as such. I want exclude leave that row in "Buckets" blank and then on 8/1-8/31 pick back up and categorize it as 0-30 days.

Comment: I tried adding myTable[NRU] <> "NRU" to the filter functions in each of the variables but it did not do what I was expecting. Is there something I'm missing here? Is there an easy way to do this? Let me know if you need another example of the table I'm looking at.

Comment: Word of advice: don't ask a question and then, after you get an answer to that question, state it's only half the problem. What you could do is add a conditional new Mileage column, that is 1 when the NRU column has an "NRU"-value. Replace the old Mileage column with the new one in my answer.

Comment: I apologize for that, still new to the community. But overall, I got it to work. Thank you so much for all of your help! It's much appreciated.

Comment: Don't worry about it. Glad i could help.